# Best Practices for migrating python2 to python3 in django

Tags: django, database, python-2to3, code-migration

It will be more helpful if you answer the following questions as well.

1. Dealing with `models.CharField`.

   - In python2, how the CharField value is stored in the database and how it is different from the value which is going to store in python3.

Comment: It isn't. In Python-2.x it could store both a `str` and `unicode`, and these two types have merged in Python-3.x.

Comment: That means there will be no issues with database regarding the Charfield. Right?

Comment: no. It will store the data in a VARCHAR. If there is a problem with querying, this likely is due to the COLLATION of the database.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying the doubt.
Would you share your experience if you have already worked regarding these migration related things if possible?